# Value of the logcontract $Q^T(t,S)$ with payoff $Q(T,S)=-2lnS_T$

Tags: stochastic-volatility, present-value, payoff

Why is the value of the log-contract (Neuberger ,1990) with payoff $Q(T,S) = -2\ln S$ given by
$$
Q^T(t,S)=-2e^{-r(T-t)}\left(\ln S + (r-q)(T-t)-\frac{\hat\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)\right)
$$
?
It is reported in the book Bergomi 2015 at equation 3.8.

Comment: @nbbo2 can you provide the exact reference?

Comment: https://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/%5BJournal%20of%20Portfolio%20Management,%20Neuberger%5D%20The%20Log%20Contract%20-%20A%20New%20Instrument%20to%20Hedge%20Volatility.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Black-Scholes model, risk-neutral the dynamics of $S_t$ are given by
$$
dS_t = (r-q)S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t.
$$
Using Itô's lemma, we can find the dynamics of the log-process
$$
d\log S_t = \left((r-q) - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)dt  + \sigma dW_t.
$$

From this we can see that $\log S_T - \log S_t  \sim N\left((r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t), \sigma^2(T-t) \right)$, and we can derive the formula for $Q^T(t,S)$ by taking the risk-neutral expectation of $Q(T,S_T)$.